# getting formatting data in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm having trouble extracting the styles from an excel worksheet using openpyxl, in the case below I'm creating a spreadsheet, and I can see that the formatting is correct, but I don't know how to get that data back.

In my real use case I'm just reading a file - I'm not the one creating it, so I'd like to be able to programmatically retrieve the formatting.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
from openpyxl.style import Color, Fill
#this is all setup
wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = 'c:\\temp\\test.xlsx'

ws = wb.worksheets[0]

ws.title = 'test'

ws.cell('A1').value = 'foo'
ws.cell('A1').style.font.bold = True

ws.cell('B1').value = 'bar'
ws.cell('B1').style.fill.fill_type = Fill.FILL_SOLID
ws.cell('B1').style.fill.start_color.index = Color.DARKYELLOW

wb.save(filename = dest_filename )
#setup complete    

book = load_workbook( filename = dest_filename )

sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name('test')

#value work properly
print sheet.cell('A1').value #returns foo
print sheet.cell('B1').value #return bar

#formatting does not - THIS IS THE PROBLEM CODE
print sheet.cell('A1').style.font.bold #returns False
print sheet.cell('B1').style.fill.fill_type #returns none
print sheet.cell('B1').style.fill.start_color.index #returns FFFFFFFF

print sheet.cell('B1').has_style #returns true
#but these 2 return the same values! even thought C1 was never set and should be different
print sheet.get_style('A1')
print sheet.get_style('C1')
```

Comment: Could trim this code down to just the part that's giving you trouble?

Comment: it's actually pretty minimal already - if you have openpyxl installed you can copy-paste and it should work.  If you just want to see the specific things that are breaking, it's the last 6 lines - all the print statements (except the has_style) are returning the "wrong" values

Comment: what `openpyxl` version are you using? I've tried your code locally - it reads styles properly.

Comment: I was using 1.5.8, now with 1.6.2 it works as expected.  Thanks for the help!  If you post the comment as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change from openpyxl.style import Color, Fill to
from openpyxl.styles import Color, Fill

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).