# Formatting in OpenPyxl with use_iterators = True

Tags: python, openpyxl

This is similar to my earlier question [getting formating data in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428977/getting-formating-data-in-openpyxl)  The only real difference is that now I really want to use the optimized workbook for the speed increase.

Basically I can't figure out how to retrieve formatting details when I use the optimized reader.  Here's a toy sample, the comments explain what I'm seeing on the print statements.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a better way to retrieve formatting details?

Also, if anyone knows of a different excel reader for python that supports xlsx + retrieving formatting I'm open to changing!  (I've already tried xlrd, and while that does support xlsx in the newer builds it doesn't yet support formatting)

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
from openpyxl.style import Color, Fill
#this is all setup
wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = 'c:\\temp\\test.xlsx'

ws = wb.worksheets[0]

ws.title = 'test'

ws.cell('A1').value = 'foo'
ws.cell('A1').style.font.bold = True

ws.cell('B1').value = 'bar'
ws.cell('B1').style.fill.fill_type = Fill.FILL_SOLID
ws.cell('B1').style.fill.start_color.index = Color.YELLOW

wb.save(filename = dest_filename )
#setup complete    

book = load_workbook( filename = dest_filename, use_iterators = True )

sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name('test')

for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        print cell.coordinate
        print cell.internal_value 
        print cell.style_id #returns different numbers here (1, and 2 in case anyone is interested)
        print sheet.get_style(cell.coordinate).font.bold #returns False for both
        print sheet.get_style(cell.coordinate).fill.fill_type #returns none for bothe
        print sheet.get_style(cell.coordinate).fill.start_color.index #returns FFFFFFFF (white I believe) for both
        print

import openpyxl
print openpyxl.__version__ #returns 1.6.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The style_ID appears to be the index for where you can find the style information in workbook -> shared_styles (book.shared_styles or sheet.parent.shared_styles).

In some workbooks this works flawlessly; but, I've also found in other workbooks the style_ID is greater than the length of shared_styles giving me "Out of range" Exceptions when I try to access said styles.